# .net core 2.2 unable to handle encrypted string in body even though mediatype says application/json

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a third party that is posting a request to my API... they are posting encrypted text as the body but also including application/json as the Content-Type. Is there any way I can get .Net Core 2.2 to handle this... I have tried...

```
    [HttpPost("/callback/thirdparty")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Thirdparty([FromBody]dynamic body)
    {
```

and

```
    [HttpPost("/callback/thirdparty")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Thirdparty([FromBody]string body)
    {
```

But neither work.

```
    Request Headers
    Content-Type: "application/json"
    Accept: "*/*"
    Cache-Control: "no-cache"
    Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"
    Content-Length: 155
    Connection: "keep-alive"
    Request Body
    z42T\/+j28AyZRslEXIZx9Vt87D1HOdMZqukzIi7s4gbtZqtdJJjJtQMkZ+O9vG3VlfJZ+6Ro7vwE\n6nTSwqczc2SwPiAaRjgv7nauvR2E3d8tk8zbVD+Ck6TL12hJHFHVySAP7I482lQU+SmE31OmDw==
```

Comment: Well, put simply, what you're posting is NOT Json and the correct thing would be for the server to return 400 - Bad Request. This is binary data, e.g. `application/octet-stream`, and you'd need to write your own custom serializer to read this.

What you're doing with your answer is circumventing web conventions, and making the code somewhat harder to test. Just FYI.

Comment: I agree... but this call is coming from a third party who is not going to change their convention... so I have managed to handle it in my answer... my preference would have been for them to change the Content-Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [HttpPost("/callback/thirdparty")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Thirdparty()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            {
                var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Now I have a string in body!